# store batch data from aws sqs to aws s3 using aws lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to get polled messages (iot data) in aws sqs from aws lambda (nodejs runtime) and trying to store it in aws s3 bucket. But I'm getting error in storing it.

Here is my payload:-

`{      "device_name" : "xxx",      "temp":23.44,      "humidity":33.44,      "timestamp"  : epoch timestamp  }`

Here is my code:-

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
export const putInS3 = async (device_name,year,month,day) => {
        let bucketName = "my-bucket-name";
        const client = new S3Client({Bucket:bucketName,key:`${device_name}/${year}/${month}/${day}/`});
        try {
            const putObj = new PutObjectCommand(client);
            const sendRequest = await client.send(putObj);
            console.log(sendRequest);
        } catch (err) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        }
}
export const handler = async(event) => {
    // TODO implement
    // console.log(s3Bucket);
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const day = date.getDate();
    event.Records.forEach(record => {
    let { body } = record;
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    let device_name = body.device_name;
    putInS3(device_name,year,month,day);
    console.log(body + "    ");
    });
};
```

The above code gives following error :

```
Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Bucket.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are providing an incorrect value to PutObjectCommand. You are passing the client but you should be passing parameters.

This should work:

```
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

const s3Client = new S3Client({'region': 'us-east-1'});

export const putInS3 = async (device_name,year,month,day, body) => {
        let bucketName = "my-bucket-name";
        const parameters = {
         'Bucket': bucketName,
         'Key': `${device_name}/${year}/${month}/${day}/`,
         'Body': body
        }
        try {
            const putObj = new PutObjectCommand(parameters);
            const sendRequest = await s3Client.send(putObj);
            console.log(sendRequest);
        } catch (err) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        }
}
```

Comment: Implemented the mentioned solution but still the file is not written in s3 bucket

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It just shows no error in cloudwatch logs not even the console.log(sendRequest) is getting printed